# webpack.optimize.UglifyJSPlugin does not work while uglifyjs-webpack-plugin works

Tags: javascript, webpack, uglifyjs

I have 2 files `app.js` & `math.js`

It contains the following code -

## app.js

```
import { sum } from "./math";

console.log("");

console.log(sum(2, 3));
```

## math.js

```
export const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
export const multiply = (m, n) => m * n;
```

## webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const config = {
    entry: "./app.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin()
        // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin() doesn't work
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

The complete code is available at https://github.com/deadcoder0904/webpack-treeshake

The problem is `UglifyJsPlugin` works but `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()` doesn't work

My `webpack` version is v3.11.0

Comment: Please read the docs: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/

Comment: I already did & tried it thats why asking. My version is 3.11.0 whereas in the top it says webpack =< 3.0.0.

Comment: What exactly did you try about "webpack =< v3.0.0 currently contains v0.4.6 of this plugin under webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin as an alias. For usage of the latest version (v1.0.0), please follow the instructions below." ?

Comment: I don't get it. I am using version 3.11.0 which is greater than 3.0.0. Ohh sorry read it again. Is it for v4.0.0?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Is it for v4.0.0". But `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` and `UglifyJsPlugin` do not refer to the same version.

Comment: I was talking about Webpack v4.0.0. Yeah, its different versions but I guess Uglify supported TreeShaking. Now I tried webpack@next i.e. v4.0.0-beta-1 & it giving error 'Error: webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.minimize instead.'

Comment: Ok so I got the answer. Thanks for helping out. I'll post it now so it helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting answer to my own question. Thanks @str for helping out.

I was using different versions of Uglify JS, not sure if that was the problem.

So I tried installing webpack version 4 which is now in beta so I had to do install `webpack@next`. Also, `webpack-cli` is now its own package so I had to install it too. Earlier, it was bundled with `webpack` itself.

After installing both `webpack@next` & `webpack-cli`, I changed my `webpack.config,js` to look like -

## webpack.config,js

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const config = {
    entry: "./app.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

And ran the following to generate bundle with TreeShaking

`webpack --optimize-minimize --mode production`

The complete code is available at https://github.com/deadcoder0904/webpack-treeshake

Checkout my other answer to [TreeShake with Lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816704/lodash-not-treeshaking-with-webpack-with-webpack-4) which does all the treeshaking