# Lodash not TreeShaking with Webpack with Webpack 4?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I want to tree shake `lodash` as well as my unused `multiply` function from the generated bundle from `webpack`

I have 2 main files `app.js` & `math.js`

It contains the following code -

## app.js

```
import map from "lodash/map";

import { sum } from "./math";

console.log("");

console.log(`2 + 3 = ${sum(2, 3)}`);

map([1, 2, 3], x => {
    console.log(x);
});
```

## math.js

```
export const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
export const multiply = (m, n) => m * n;
```

## webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const UglifyJSPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const Jarvis = require("webpack-jarvis");

let plugins = [new Jarvis()];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") plugins.push(new UglifyJSPlugin());

const config = {
    entry: "./app.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins
};

module.exports = config;
```

My `npm` script look like -

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --optimize-minimize --mode development",
    "dev:watch": "webpack --watch --optimize-minimize --mode development",
    "prod": "webpack -p --optimize-minimize --mode production",
    "prod:watch": "webpack -p --watch --optimize-minimize --mode production",
    "start": "npm run prod",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist"
  }
```

The complete code is available at https://github.com/deadcoder0904/webpack-treeshake

I've tried using UglifyJSPlugin but in the generated bundle it still shows my unused `multiply` function from `math.js`. Also, the `production` bundle generated from `npm run prod` remains `20kB` which is a lot & I see a lot of `lodash` stuff included as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer

To use `lodash` with tree shaking we should first install `lodash-es` & then remove the `lodash` dependency

Also, it should not be transpiled first, so we make our `.babelrc` file as follows -

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Notice, that setting `modules` to `false` makes it not transpile

And now the bundle reduces to **16.2kB** & **5.79kB gzip**

Some code from `lodash` module will still be used because it is required to run `lodash` itself, other than that `multiply` function from `./math.js` isn't added in the resulting bundle

I also needed [lodash-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/lodash/lodash-webpack-plugin) for it to be working

Treeshaking works

I've made some basic repos solving the stated problem -

https://github.com/deadcoder0904/webpack-exam

https://github.com/deadcoder0904/webpack-treeshake

Comment: I get `Unexpected token import` after I try to start express with server-side-rendering.

Comment: @Tomasz its because you need to transpile it to `require` using something like `babel` otherwise use `require`

Comment: I have found an interesting article about it about how to configure it either via babel or with typescript: https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/tree-shake-lodash-with-webpack-jest-and-typescript-2734fa13b5cd

Comment: @Braulio the contents of that article aren't really relevant anymore (see the Aug. 2017 update) that was relevant before lodash pure modules and webpack 4.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @deadcoder0904's answer, here's how to do the same with `babel-loader` in webpack 4 (instead of using .babelrc):

```
...
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    plugins: ['lodash'],
                    presets: [['env', { modules: false }]]
                }
            }
        },
```

Note: I wasn't able to get this to work without explicitly importing from 'lodash-es' (even if I pointed lodash-es to lodash in my tsconfig (I'm using typescript). If someone can get this working without having to use the special `import { map } from 'lodash-es';` and instead with `import { map } from 'lodash';` it would be great to know how!